# Mongodb aggregating/grouping by column and counting specific columns

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

We've setup a basic application which writes events to a mongo instance. Here's a sample write:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("50fee761472870a3d610956e"),
    "user_id" : "pa-XXXXXXXXX",
    "event_id" : 1,
    "date_created" : 1337798856,
    "url" : "http://news.yahoo.com/australian-tycoon-worlds-richest-woman-103810206.html"
```

What we'd like to do is retrieve results grouped by URL and a count of certain event_id's. Like event_grouping_a might consist of event_ids 1,6,35 and event_grouping_b might consist of 2,66,103. A sample output would look something like this:

```
{
    url: "http://news.yahoo.com/australian-tycoon-worlds-richest-woman-103810206.html",
    event_grouping_a: 46,
    event_grouping_b: 34
},
{
    url: "http://news.yahoo.com/another-cool-story",
    event_grouping_a: 105,
    event_grouping_b: 59
}
```

Any idea on how to perform this type of aggregation/grouping? The end goal is to have it in PHP, but I've messed with doing it in the mongod console to no avail. I can get it to group by URL, but I can't get it do display both event types under a single parent URL. It spits out something like this:

```
{
    url: "http://news.yahoo.com/australian-tycoon-worlds-richest-woman-103810206.html",
    event_grouping_a: 46
    event_grouping_b: 0
},
{
    url: "http://news.yahoo.com/australian-tycoon-worlds-richest-woman-103810206.html",
    event_grouping_a: 0
    event_grouping_b: 34
},
...
```

The above two should be merged into 1, but I can't for the life of me figure it out ... any suggestions?

Comment: should include the query you tried in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't necessarily like the `$or` statements to make this work, but this query should work for you from php if you are using the 1.3+ mongo driver:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient('dbinfo');
$collection = $mongo->selectCollection( 'dbName', 'collectionName' );

$pipeline = array(
    array( 
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$url',
            'event_grouping_a' => array( 
                '$sum' => array( 
                    '$cond' => array( 
                        array( '$or' => array(
                            array( '$eq' => array( '$event_id', 1 ) ),
                            array( '$eq' => array( '$event_id', 6 ) ),
                            array( '$eq' => array( '$event_id', 35 ) )
                        ) ), 1, 0 ) 
                )   
            ),
            'event_grouping_b' => array(
                '$sum' => array(
                    '$cond' => array(
                        array( '$or' => array(
                            array( '$eq' => array( '$event_id', 2 ) ),
                            array( '$eq' => array( '$event_id', 66 ) ),
                            array( '$eq' => array( '$event_id', 103 ) )
                        ) ), 1, 0 )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
$results = $collection->aggregate( $pipeline );
```

--

```
var_dump( $results );
array(2) { 
    ["result"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["_id"]=> string(40) "http://news.yahoo.com/another-cool-story" 
            ["event_grouping_a"]=> int(2) 
            ["event_grouping_b"]=> int(1) 
        } 
        [1]=> array(3) { 
            ["_id"]=> string(75) "http://news.yahoo.com/australian-tycoon-worlds-richest-woman-103810206.html" 
            ["event_grouping_a"]=> int(3) 
            ["event_grouping_b"]=> int(4) 
        } 
    } 
    ["ok"]=> float(1) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you feel like this solution would scale if the record set spanned 200-400K records?

Comment: I would suggest evaluating the use of an index, so you aren't unnecessarily doing full scans.  You should be ok, but you may also want to check out using upserts to preaggregate this data in a separate collection - there is examples in the mongo docs.